# Passing pointer to a function

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

```
//old and auqHdr are data structures of type gblAuqEntry and auQ respectively
//I traverse through the list 'auqHdr' and when I match the element 'old', I need to remove it

removeAUfromNodeAUQ(&old, &auqHdr);  


//Function implementation
static void removeAUfromNodeAUQ(gblAuqEntry *old, auQ *auqH)
{
    auQ *auqPtr, *prev;
int found =0;
for (auqPtr = auqH; auqPtr; auqPtr = auqPtr->nxt)
{
    if (something)
        prev = auqPtr;
    else
    {
        prev->nxt = old->nxt;
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

I am trying to remove the element 'old' in the list 'auqHdr'.

The error I am getting is "declaration is incompatible with previous "removeAUfromNodeAUQ""
Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if your code used variables that were vaguely readable. If 'auqHdr' is a list, just call it it 'myList' so that the people here can more easily understand what your code is doing. It is a good idea to have your variable names be descriptive and readable in general, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the function before *declaring* it, C implies a return type of `int`, not `void`.

You should add this declaration in the header or at the top of your file to address the problem:

```
static void removeAUfromNodeAUQ(gblAuqEntry *old, auQ *auqH);
```

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight ! This was it. I forgot to declare it ahead of using it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your code is exactly as you posted, then this:

```
removeAUfromNodeAUQ(&old, &auqHdr);
```

Is not a function call, it is a function declaration.  You then define it, but with a different signature.  In that context you are forward declaring a function. C assumes a return type of int for you.

Comment: Thanks Ed S and dasblinkenlight.